# Copying a String to a Variable or a Register from Within a Function

Tags: vimscript

I want to write a function which copies, say, the last word of the next line which contains `keyword` into a variable say `var` or any named register say `l`.

I did something inelegant:

```
function! CopyIntoVar()
          "go to the next line which contains keyword
    /keyword

          "go to the last word and copy it like one does using normal mode
    normal $vb"ly
    let var=@l
endfunction
```

Is there a better way?

(I am not particularly interested in the last word. Just want to see how to copy a desired string into a register or variable).

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`expand()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expand%28%29) function:

```
Expand wildcards and the following special keywords in `{expr}`.
```

with the `<cword>` or `<cWORD>` special keywords:

```
<cword>     word under the cursor
<cWORD>     WORD under the cursor
```

Your function would then look like:

```
function! CopyIntoVar()
    " Go to the next line which contains keyword
    /keyword

    " Go to the last word
    normal $

    " Get the value of the word under the cursor
    let var = expand('<cword>')
endfunction
```

This still has 2 side-effects though:

- It will move the cursor
- Using `/` will set the `"/` register (and pressing `n` now searches for that pattern).

This may or may not be what you want.

We can use the `search()` function to avoid setting `"/`, and use `getpos()` and `setpos()` to set & restore the cursor position:

Another advantage of `search()` it's not affected by settings such as `wrapscan` or `magic`; it always behaves the same.

```
function! CopyIntoVar()
    " Save cursor position
    let l:save_cursor = getpos(".")   

    " Go to the next line which contains keyword
    call search('keyword')

    " Go to the last word
    normal $

    " Get the value of the word under the cursor
    let var = expand('<cword>')

    " Restore cursor position
    call setpos('.', l:save_cursor)   
endfunction
```

Comment: Very helpful. Can you tell me just one thing though. Is it necessary use a variable of the type `l:save_cursor`. Woudn't just `save_cursor` suffice?

Comment: @caffeinemachine Yeah, the `l:` is mostly optional, I like typing it anyway, but you don't have to ;-) Just remember that if a special (`v:`) variable exists it takes precedence.